# Como introduzir novo texto em texto ja existente em textbox

Tags: vb.net

Eu estou a tentar introdizir na primeira linha de um texto ja importado no textbox a data e hora , mas quando aplico com este codigo ele faz uma nova linha mas no fim e eu preciso de aplicar na primeira linha.
este e o meu codigo actual

```
TextBox1.Text &= Environment.NewLine & time.ToString(format)
```

Answer (score 0):

Bom acabei por encontrar uma solução para o problema que era destinado para richtextbox e fiz algumas alteraçoes para funcionar com textbox.
Codigo encontrado aqui
[Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30380852/vb-net-2010-append-text-always-at-top-of-a-richtextbox)

este e o meu codigo actual

```
TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Insert(0, time.ToString(format) + vbNewLine)
```